# How to focus an Outlook 2010 custom ribbon tab

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a custom Outlook 2010 Ribbon tab that has the type Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment.

In that tab, I have several buttons that change the current appointment item, and call its `Save` method. However, that method always changes the focus to the first tab of the inspector. I want the focus to remain on my custom tab.

Here is my current code:

```
private void ButtonSaveAppointment(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = (Outlook.Inspector)this.Context;
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)inspector.CurrentItem;

    appointment.Save();
    this.RibbonUI.ActivateTab(this.Tabs[0].ControlId.ToString());
}
```

This does not work for me. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am also having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use in my load event:

```
ThisRibbonCollection ribbonCollection = Globals.Ribbons[_inspector];
ribbonCollection.RibbonSMS.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("the_name_of_the_ribbon_tab");
```

And that would correspond to what i see in your code:

```
this.RibbonUI.ActivateTab(this.Tabs[0].ControlId.ToString());
```

That code fires well in the load event, but i tested it and it does not work when you are calling it from a function. Please try and move it to the load event and you will see that the code works. My guess is that it does not work properly from a method but just form the load event.

Good luck